# What is breaking away/peeling off in military lingo?

Tags: military

About *breaking away* or *peeling off*:

- Is this synonymous of a *wing over*?
- Is this a signal to your wing mates that you are leaving formation deliberately to engage the enemy?
- Does that mean you would subsequently roll on your back to scan for possible enemy aircraft below, complete the roll, and proceed toward the enemy?

Answer (score 3):

I believe these are slang terms for element separation, where a leader and wingman break formation from each other either in order to reform in a new formation for tactical purposes e.g. Spread formation etc. fly a tactical maneuver to defeat a threat like a champagne or in order to land flying an overhead approach.  Wingovers are aerobatic maneuvers, very similar to Lazy Eights, intended to teach student pilots the art of flying the airplane with constantly varying stick and rudder inputs and are not involved with element separation.